# Join two entities in symfony2 using doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

There are two entities. **Ticket** and **Device**.

In **device orm** there is

```
<one-to-many target-entity="Ticket" mapped-by="Device" field="ticket"/>
<many-to-one field="category" target-entity="Category"/>
```

in **ticket orm**

```
<many-to-one field="device"  target-entity="Device"/>
```

I want to implement a filter where the user can filter tickets by device's category. How can I do that? I tried with

```
$qb->select(array('t', 'd'))
        ->from('MyBundle:Ticket', 't')
        ->innerJoin('t.device', 'd')
        ->where("t.category.name = 'Cashbox'");;
```

But this gives me an error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 88: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->where("t.category.name = 'Cashbox'");;
```

is incorrect. You have to join the category table:

```
$qb
    ->select(array('t', 'd'))
    ->from('MyBundle:Ticket', 't')
    ->innerJoin('t.device', 'd')
    ->innerJoin('d.category', 'c')
    ->where("c.name = 'Cashbox'");
```

Comment: this does not work either, [Semantical Error] line 0, col 94 near 'c WHERE c.name': Error: Class Ticket has no association named category

Comment: Oh, it's device that has a category relation. Updated